# C#/Selenium: javascript error: Cannot read property 'fireEvent' of null

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium

I'm trying to click an angular `mat-checkbox`. Doing so by xpath or ID directly with Selenium results in an error related to "other element would receive click". Searching around led me to believe executing Javascript via Selenium would be the solution.

The following JavaScript works in Chrome if I go to `Developer Tools`, `Sources` and click "Run":

```
function eventFire(el, etype) {
                if (el.fireEvent) {
                    el.fireEvent('on' + etype);
                } else {
                    var evObj = document.createEvent('Events');
                    evObj.initEvent(etype, true, false);
                    el.dispatchEvent(evObj);
                }
                };
eventFire(document.getElementById('mat-checkbox-2-input'), 'click')
```

This does, indeed, click the checkbox with ID `mat-checkbox-2-input`.

However, writing the code in C# using Selenium results in:

`OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : javascript error: Cannot read property 'fireEvent' of null`

My C# code:

```
        public void TickCheckbox()
        {
            var jsExecutor = (IJavaScriptExecutor)Driver;
            var script = 
                @"function eventFire(el, etype) {
                if (el.fireEvent) {
                    el.fireEvent('on' + etype);
                } else {
                    var evObj = document.createEvent('Events');
                    evObj.initEvent(etype, true, false);
                    el.dispatchEvent(evObj);
                }
                };
                eventFire(document.getElementById('mat-checkbox-2-input'), 'click')";

            jsExecutor.ExecuteScript(script);
        }
```

Why is `el.fireEvent` null when it's Javascript executed from Selenium, and not Javascript executed by myself in the browser? Why does the very same JavaScript code behave differently in the two environments?

Comment: Try your code on https://material.angular.io/components/checkbox/overview using 'mat-checkbox-1-input' 'Check me!' . Its working fine . May be document.getElementById('mat-checkbox-2-input') retuning null as element is not available when script is getting executed.